# Switching on 2-port KVM resets mouse sensitivity (Ubuntu 20.04, 20.10)

Tags: gnome, keyboard, mouse, keyboard-layout, kvm-switch

I have a 2 port HDMI KVM switch.  Recently, on Ubuntu 20.04 and on Ubuntu 20.10 (tried an upgrade to fix it), when I switch back to the Ubuntu machine, the mouse sensitivity resets.  This only started happening within the last week or so.

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart gnome fixes it, but does not fix on the lock screen, and it breaks again when switching back and forth on the KVM.

This may also happen with unplugging the mouse and plugging it back in but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I noticed later that my Ubuntu OS was originally installed from 16.10 and upgraded several times since. I reinstalled a fresh 20.04 and the problem went away.

Comment: Correction, problem is not completely solved. Keyboard stays as Dvorak but mouse sensitivity resets. I have to go into mouse settings to turn it back down each time.

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/1553 looks like it's related -- found this on https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3380

Comment: Could you update your question to focus just on the remaining mouse problem? This might help people find the issue and offer a solution.